# How to limit in sqllite query?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

```
 public String readQuestion(int i)//Used to read the data from the Des.db file where id is given and we choose id randomly
{
    String Ans = "";//string that contains the required field  note that Ans is just a local string not related to Answer or Option...
    Cursor c = sqlite.rawQuery("SELECT " + Question + " FROM " + Table_name + " LIMIT " + 5 + " WHERE " + uid + " = " + i + "", null);//cursor to that query
    if (c.moveToFirst())
        Ans = c.getString(0);
    else
        Ans = "";
    return Ans;
}
```

I want to add a limit in this query . like LIMIT 10.

Comment: Please do not edit your old question to make a totally new question as the previous answers are invalidated! Instead, you are welcome to ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)  that will attract new answers

Answer (score 1):

You're close. The `LIMIT` keyword needs to be at the **end** of the query. Where you currently have:

```
"SELECT " + Question + 
" FROM " + Table_name + 
" LIMIT " + 5 + 
" WHERE " + uid + " = " + i + ""
```

This should be

```
"SELECT " + Question + 
" FROM " + Table_name + + 
" WHERE " + uid + " = " + i +
" LIMIT " + 5 + ""
```

Answer (score 0):

please consider small change.

```
Cursor c = sqlite.rawQuery("SELECT " + Question + " FROM " + Table_name  
           + " WHERE  " + uid + " = " + i  + " LIMIT " + "5", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c = sqlite.rawQuery("SELECT " + Question + " FROM " + Table_name + " WHERE " + uid + " = " + i + " LIMIT 5 ", null);
```

Limit is at the end of the query.You should look at the link for detailed information.
[sqlite limit statement](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/select_limit.php)

Comment: Cursor c = sqlite.rawQuery("SELECT " + Question + " FROM " + Table_name 
          +  " WHERE " + uid + " = " + i +  " LIMIT 5 " , null);//cursor to that query
Nothing happening .